# How do I configure a router to group multiple devices to multiple public IPs?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

I am renting 5 static IPs from my ISP. I want 9 smartphones to use 3 different public IPs when connected to WiFi. I've read a little about the term managed switch and virtual LAN (VLAN). Most seem to only have wired ports. Since these smartphones will connect via WiFi, it is not clear if the set up I want is possible.

| Group A | Public IP 172.110.32.51 |
| --- | --- |
| Phone 1 | 192.168.1.101 |
| Phone 2 | 192.168.1.102 |
| Phone 3 | 192.168.1.103 |

| Group B | Public IP 172.110.32.52 |
| --- | --- |
| Phone 4 | 192.168.1.104 |
| Phone 5 | 192.168.1.105 |
| Phone 6 | 192.168.1.106 |

| Group C | Public IP 172.110.32.53 |
| --- | --- |
| Phone 7 | 192.168.1.107 |
| Phone 8 | 192.168.1.108 |
| Phone 9 | 192.168.1.109 |

Comment: having multiple public IPs is usually done to Host content (incoming connections from the Internet, like if you ran your own websites). what you are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Does the router being used support 5 WAN IPs _(that usually requires 5 WAN interfaces)_? Short of using either opensource firmware [OpenWrt],  one router per WAN IP, or a router configured with multi-WAN [MWAN] _(normally used for fail-over, not assigning separate WAN IPs to different non-server clients)_, what's being asked is likely not possible. If the router supports 5 WAN IPs, you could create 3 separate vLANs, routing each one to a separate WAN interfaces _(this would require open source firmware, such as OpenWrt, or a business class router that supports this type of configuration)_.

Comment: @JW0914 Let's say each port can be assigned a unique WAN IP. How will the WiFi part work? Are you suggesting each port have its own access point? Would a OpenWRT installed a wireless/wired router combo allow w/o additional hardware?

Comment: I'm unsure how you would configure that because it's not sane networking. This appears to be an X Y problem - could you please elaborate a bit on your reasoning/what the end goal achievement is, as that would help folks to be better able to help find a solution. OpenWrt can route multiple WAN IPs by installing the mwan package, however mwan is wonky in and of itself, with its main purpose being failover; however, vlan setup on OpenWrt is simple

Comment: @JW0914 My roommate and I both have insane work security where one of the requirements is to use our wireless laptops with a specific IP address only. Maybe OpenWRT is not ideal. I can buy a managed switch which I think might do the job and create VLANs based on the MAC address of the respective devices.

Comment: @Sun Any router OS, including OpenWrt, can create vLANs based on MACs - that's not the issue - having one router manage two or more WAN IPs and routing traffic to two or more WAN IPs independently of fail-over is, as that's not a sane networking setup. If you're using your ISP's modem/router combo in order to gain access to more than one WAN IP on the router side, and the combo doesn't offer the ability to independently route traffic based on the WAN IP, using separate routers for each WAN IP would be easiest. You don't have to use normal routers, as a Pi or Arduino running OpenWrt would work.

Comment: _Cont'd..._ If you have a Pi or Arduino laying around, it would need a physical ethernet port for WAN and a WiFi card for LAN, but if you don't have one laying around, a cheap AC router and the required components for the Pi/Arduino would be about the same cost. If you do choose to buy a router, I always recommend buying one that's [OpenWrt compatible](https://openwrt.org/supported_devices), as OEMs only provide firmware security updates for 1 - 2 yrs, whereas OpenWrt releases updates at least twice a year, or you can compile your own whenever you want.

Comment: @JW0914 Never asked about failover or multiple WANs. This is multiple IPs with the same ISP. Failover is nice to have, but not part of my question to simplify things. I bought a Dell managed switch, hopefully that'll work. I saw that it can create VLANs based on MAC address. This is all new to me, so wish me luck. If you post your answer about router OS & vLAN based on MACs, I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: @Sun I believe you may be misunderstanding... If you have 5 static IPs assigned from your ISP, those are WAN IPs and AFAIK, what you're attempting to do isn't possible because it's not sane networking. When you login to your router's WebUI, are you seeing 5 WAN IPs, as that would usually require 5 separate WAN interfaces connected to 5 different WAN ethernet ports on the modem? A managed switch is not going to be a solution, as switches route LAN side traffic, not traffic to WAN, as that requires a stateful firewall on a router

Comment: @JW0914 Yes, it seems I need an enterprise router, not a switch.

Comment: @Sun That's not going to help, as the lack of an Enterprise router isn't the issue.